# Can't duplicate a product in Craft Commerce?

Tags: plugins, ecommerce, plugin-craftcommerce

I can't seem to find a way to duplicate a product in Craft Commerce.

I've duplicated articles before, with the "save as new" feature... But can't find anything similar for products.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Added in [Craft Commerce 1.1.1196](https://craftcommerce.com/changelog#build1196).

---

There currently isn't a native way, but it sounds like a great [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/295386-commerce)!

Comment: Indeed, and someone already did it ahead of me: http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/295386-commerce/suggestions/10911543--save-and-add-another-on-the-create-product-entry

Comment: 'Save as new product' is now available - it was added in Commerce 1.1.1196

Comment: Is this also possible in Commerce 2?
It seems the option isn't there.